# Sorting not working when User sort columns

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datatable, datagridview

I have created a note taking app in WPF with C# for training purposes.
I put in some data and saved it in a datatable which is a datagridview in WPF. The data consists of a title you put in the textbox "Title" and a message that you put in the textbox "Message". Now I would like to read out the data I put in. So, when I select first row and press "Read", "1" appears in the title textbox and "a" in the "Message" textbox, same holds when I select the 2nd and 3rd row.
[image: Before sorting]

Now, I press on the "Title" to sort the data grid view and again I am selecting the 3rd row, which appears in the datagridview as "1", and press "Read". Well, as you can see, the number "3" appears and not "1"...therefore, it seems that the datagridview was sorted, but not the datatable holding the values...

I dont have an idea how to solve that, as looking for a solution didnt help me...I guess I just didnt understand the Microsoft Docs well...so I thought you might help me out?

Thanks in advance, and here is ofc the cs and xaml code:

[image: After sorting]

**cs code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NoteTaking_App
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataTable table;
    int indexSelected; //Index of selected row
    //indexSelected = dgrid_data.SelectedIndex;
  
    
    private void MB(string text, string title)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        

    }

    private void form_Main_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(String));
        dgrid_data.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
        

        dgrid_data.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                



    }


    private void bttn_new_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_message.Clear();
        txt_title.Clear();
    }

    private void bttn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_title.Text))
        {
            MB("Please put in a Title", "title missing");
        }

        else
        {
            table.Rows.Add(txt_title.Text, txt_message.Text);
            txt_message.Clear();
            txt_title.Clear();
        }
        
    }

    private void bttn_read_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        indexSelected = dgrid_data.SelectedIndex;

        if (indexSelected > -1)
        {
            txt_title.Text = table.Rows[indexSelected].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            txt_message.Text = table.Rows[indexSelected].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        }

        else if (table.Rows.Count ==0) 
        {
            MB("There are no saved rows to read", "Selection missing");
        }

        else
        {
            MB("Please select a row", "Selection missing");
        }


    }


    private void bttn_delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        indexSelected = dgrid_data.SelectedIndex;
        
        if (indexSelected > -1)
        {
            this.table.Rows[indexSelected].Delete();
        }

        else if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MB("There are no saved rows to delete", "Selection missing");
        }

        else
        {
            MB("Please select a row", "Selection missing");
        }

    }

    

       
    }
}
```

**xaml code**

```
<Window x:Class="NoteTaking_App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteTaking_App"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Note Taking" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="form_Main" Loaded="form_Main_Loaded">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="117*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="63*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid_data" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="192,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="372"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.554,0.552" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style/>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style/>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_message" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="109,116,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True">
        <TextBox.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBox.RenderTransform>
    </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="bttn_new" Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="109,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Click="bttn_new_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="bttn_save" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="48,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Grid.Column="1" Click="bttn_save_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="bttn_read" Content="Read" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="246,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Grid.Column="1" Click="bttn_read_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="bttn_delete" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="402,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Grid.Column="1" Click="bttn_delete_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_titel" Content="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="12,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" AutomationProperties.Name="Titel"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_message" Content="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="12,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_title" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="108,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275"/>

</Grid>
```

**Final code after answer implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NoteTaking_App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataTable table;       
        

        private void MB(string text, string title)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(text, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)dgrid_data.SelectedItem;

        }

        private void form_Main_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(String));
            dgrid_data.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;            

            dgrid_data.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;          
        }


        private void bttn_new_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txt_message.Clear();
            txt_title.Clear();
        }

        private void bttn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_title.Text))
            {
                MB("Please put in a Title", "title missing");
            }

            else
            {
                table.Rows.Add(txt_title.Text, txt_message.Text);
                txt_message.Clear();
                txt_title.Clear();
            }
            
        }


        private void bttn_read_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)dgrid_data.SelectedItem;

            if (dataRowView!=null)
            {
                txt_title.Text = dataRowView[0].ToString();
                txt_message.Text = dataRowView[1].ToString();
            }
            else if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MB("There are no saved rows to read", "Selection missing");
            }
            else
            {
                MB("Please select a row", "Selection missing");
            }       
        }


        private void bttn_delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)dgrid_data.SelectedItem;

            if (dataRowView!=null)
            {
                dataRowView.Delete();
            }                             
            else if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MB("There are no saved rows to delete", "Selection missing");
            }

            else
            {
                MB("Please select a row", "Selection missing");
            }

        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: You have sorted your collection but you haven't changed selected item

Comment: I dont get what you are saying..didnt I do that by clicking on a different row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `SelectedItem` to a `DataRowView` and get the column values from there:

```
private void bttn_read_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = dgrid_data.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

    if (drv != null)
    {
        txt_title.Text = drv[0].ToString();
        txt_message.Text = drv[0].ToString();
    }

    else if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MB("There are no saved rows to read", "Selection missing");
    }

    else
    {
        MB("Please select a row", "Selection missing");
    }
}
```

Same thing when you delete, i.e. use the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks you very much, works like a charm! I have still 3 things/questions I d like to   address (due to better overview each in every comment)

Comment: txt_message.Text = drv[0].ToString(); needs to be txt_message.Text = drv[1].ToString(); I know you just forgot to change...

Comment: As we need to use DataRowView drv = dgrid_data.SelectedItem as DataRowView; for the bttn_delete_Click as well, is there a better way to define it outside the method bttn_read_Click? I tried myself but it didnt work, which I expected...however, maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: was there a deeper purpose of writing DataRowView drv = dgrid_data.SelectedItem as DataRowView; instead of DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dgrid_data.SelectedItem; ? I mean both work as I have tried it, but I d prefer (DataRowView)dgrid_data.SelectedItem; as it throws the exception error if something goes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Sorting  in the UI does not change the indexes. Use SelectedItem instead of SelectedIndex

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge is limited: from the following code part, how do I display Title and Message correctly: txt_title.Text = table.Rows[indexSelected].ItemArray[0].ToString(); (this is from the bttn_read_Click event)

Comment: I meant dgrid_data.SelectedItem

Comment: its not that simple: SelectedItem is an object not an int - that leads to the question how can I access the "Title" and the "Message" in my datagridview and put em in textboxes?